# How to perform stable sort in C++ when using a custom comparator?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14, comparator, stable-sort

I am trying to write a custom comparator in C++ to sort a vector. For the sake of simplicity, I will say my sorting criteria is that all even values should come before all odd values and I am trying to write a custom comparator for this. But I need to make sure that the relative order of all even elements and all odd elements is preserved.

I am using this code:

```
bool mysort(int arg1,int arg2){
    return arg1%2==0;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> v({1,3,2,4,5,7,9,6,8,11,10,12});
    stable_sort(v.begin(),v.end(),mysort);
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Based on what I understand, when mysort() returns true, it means first argument (`arg1`) is allowed to be before the second argument (`arg2`). That why I have used `return arg1%2==0;` in the comparator.

But the output I get is `12 10 8 6 4 2 1 3 5 7 9 11`. Which means, relative order of even elements is reversed. While, relative order of odd elements is preserved.

Instead, if I use `return i%2==0 && j%2!=0;` in `mysort()` comparator, the output I get is `2 4 6 8 10 12 1 3 5 7 9 11`. Which preserves the relative order of all odd and even elements.

Why is this behavior? And what is the best way to write a custom comparator with preserving relative order of similar elements? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @NateEldredge it doesn't even do that seeing as it ignores one if its parameters. (Not sure which one since they both have the same name!) As written it says that 2 comes before 4 *and* that 4 comes before 2.

Comment: While it's not the question you asked, if you really want to stabilly reorder a container based on some property of each element, look at [stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).  Given your example it might be a better fit than a full sort algorithm.

Comment: @RaymondChen Sorry it was a typo in parameter names. It is fixed now. Params are arg1 and arg2

Comment: @DaveS I was not looking for something like stable_partition. But now it looks like it will be useful for what I was working on. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparator for `sort` and `stable_sort` must induce a *strict weak order*. Your comparator does not satisfy this condition.

One of the properties of a *strict weak order* is that for any permitted values of `i` and `j`, at most one of `mysort(i,j)` and `mysort(j,i)` can return `true`. Your comparator returns `true` for both cases when, e.g., `i=2` and `j=4`.

To fix that, you must modify your comparator. When is `arg1` "less" than `arg2`? There is only one case: When `arg1` is even and `arg2` is odd. Hence, a usable definition would be:

```
bool mysort(int arg1,int arg2){
    return arg1 % 2 == 0 && arg2 % 2 != 0;
}
```

BTW, when you define a comparator, you have at no time to think about in which order the algorithm will pass the parameters. All the (earlier, later) discussions are irrelevant. The algorithm will pass parameters in which ever order it likes. There are no guarantees.

Answer (score 4):

As I'm sure you know, `stable_sort` preserves the order of elements which compare equal.  To do this, both `mysort (i, j)` and `mysort (j, i)` must return `false` when `i` and `j` compare equal.  (It must also return `true` when `i < j` of course.)

It therefore follows that you must test both `arg1 % 2` and `arg2 % 2` in `mysort` to fulfill this contract, and `return arg1 % 2 == 0 && arg2 % 2 != 0;` does precisely what you want: it will return `false` when both `arg1 % 2` and `arg2 % 2` compare equal no matter what order the parameters are passed to it.

Comment: Thanks. So I have a question about how custom comparators work. When `mysort(i,j)` returns true, `sort()`  decides `i<j` but when `mysort(i,j)` returns false, it checks `mysort(j,i)`. If that also return false, then `sort()` decides `i==j` but if `mysort(j,i)` returns true `sort()` decides `i>j`. Is it how it works?

Comment: @JayModi Not quite. When `mysort(i,j)` returns true, then `mysort(j,i)` must not return true. If it does, then `mysort` violates a precondition of `sort`/`stable_sort`. The result is garbage a.k.a undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

STL uses a less than compare, that means std::stable_sort() is going to pass the parameters in reverse order, it will call mysort(later_object, earlier object), so the return value is true if later_object < earlier_object (copy later_object to merged output), and false if later_object >= earlier_object (copy earlier_object to merged output).

Comment: I thought it would be `mysort(earlier_object, later_object)`. How is it in case `sort` (not `stable_sort`)? here I assume `earlier_object` means object with lower index in original array.

Comment: @JayModi - preserving the order of equal elements is only done for stable sort, so the parameters to mysort() have to be (later, earlier). For the non-stable std::sort the order of equal elements doesn't matter and the order of parameters could be (earlier, later) or (later, earlier). In the case of Visual Studio both std::sort() and std::stable_sort() use insertion sort for sub-arrays <= 32 elements, and the insertion sort calls to mysort() will be (later, earlier), since it's used for stable_sort.